# VisualCode debug mode not work with redis module in nodejs App

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, debugging, redis, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When  I try debug mode visual code to nodejs app with redis implement the code (redis.js) next;

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient({host: 'localhost', port: 6379}); 

/* Connect to Redis */
router.get('/test',  async function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('entra a Redis/test');
  await client.connect();
  await client.disconnect();
  res.status(200).json({result: 'OK', data: 'Se realizado la conexión'});
});

/* GET Redis data. */
router.get('/:key',  async function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('entra a Redis/:key');
  await client.connect();
  const value = await client.get(req.params.key);
  await client.disconnect();
  res.status(200).json({result: 'OK', data: value});
});


/* POST Redis data. */
router.post('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  var xKey = req.body.key;
  var xValue = req.body.value ;
  console.log('entra a Redis/Grabación ['+xKey+']['+xValue+']');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  await client.connect();
  // const value = await client.set(req.body.key, req.body.value );
  const value = await client.set('a','b' );
  await client.disconnect();
  res.status(201).send({result: value});
});

module.exports = router;
```

This call from index.js next:

```
const serverExpress = require('express');
const app = serverExpress();
const httpRequest = require('axios');
const timeLine = require('response-time');
var redisRouter = require('./routes/redis');
app.use(timeLine());
app.use('/redis', redisRouter);
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server ok on Port 3000');
```

app is working successfully normal mode, but when i try to start in Debug mode Vcode appears next error :

```
/usr/bin/node ./src/index.js
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught SyntaxError /mnt/c/Users/rabdy/DevEnv/node_modules/redis/dist/index.js:42
            ...options?.modules
                       ^
redis.js Line 4
 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Module._load (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at <anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/rabdy/DevEnv/src/routes/redis.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Module._load (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at <anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/rabdy/DevEnv/src/index.js:9:19)
    at Module._compile (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Module._load (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (<node_internals>/internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at <anonymous> (<node_internals>/internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47)
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
```

## **REDIS INFO: **

## Server

redis_version:6.0.16
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:a3fdef44459b3ad6
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
atomicvar_api:atomic-builtin
gcc_version:11.2.0
process_id:2163
run_id:30d071d57f0f08713f04a5dbabf56f728c7b9b44
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:7950
uptime_in_days:0
hz:10
configured_hz:10
lru_clock:10354424
executable:/usr/bin/redis-server
config_file:/etc/redis/redis.conf
io_threads_active:0

## Clients

connected_clients:2
client_recent_max_input_buffer:8
client_recent_max_output_buffer:0
blocked_clients:0
tracking_clients:0
clients_in_timeout_table:0

## Memory

used_memory:914992
used_memory_human:893.55K
used_memory_rss:18026496
used_memory_rss_human:17.19M
used_memory_peak:914992
used_memory_peak_human:893.55K
used_memory_peak_perc:100.15%
used_memory_overhead:830408
used_memory_startup:809608
used_memory_dataset:84584
used_memory_dataset_perc:80.26%
allocator_allocated:1144544
allocator_active:1433600
allocator_resident:5935104
total_system_memory:8006180864
total_system_memory_human:7.46G
used_memory_lua:41984
used_memory_lua_human:41.00K
used_memory_scripts:0
used_memory_scripts_human:0B
number_of_cached_scripts:0
maxmemory:0
maxmemory_human:0B
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
allocator_frag_ratio:1.25
allocator_frag_bytes:289056
allocator_rss_ratio:4.14
allocator_rss_bytes:4501504
rss_overhead_ratio:3.04
rss_overhead_bytes:12091392
mem_fragmentation_ratio:21.17
mem_fragmentation_bytes:17175008
mem_not_counted_for_evict:0
mem_replication_backlog:0
mem_clients_slaves:0
mem_clients_normal:20504
mem_aof_buffer:0
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.2.1
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0

## Persistence

loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:0
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1688075562
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:0
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_last_cow_size:446464
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok
aof_last_cow_size:0
module_fork_in_progress:0
module_fork_last_cow_size:0

## Stats

total_connections_received:48
total_commands_processed:53
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:0
total_net_input_bytes:196731
total_net_output_bytes:39601
instantaneous_input_kbps:0.00
instantaneous_output_kbps:0.00
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:0
expired_stale_perc:0.00
expired_time_cap_reached_count:0
expire_cycle_cpu_milliseconds:144
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:23
keyspace_misses:1
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:309
migrate_cached_sockets:0
slave_expires_tracked_keys:0
active_defrag_hits:0
active_defrag_misses:0
active_defrag_key_hits:0
active_defrag_key_misses:0
tracking_total_keys:0
tracking_total_items:0
tracking_total_prefixes:0
unexpected_error_replies:0
total_reads_processed:109
total_writes_processed:67
io_threaded_reads_processed:0
io_threaded_writes_processed:0

## Replication

role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_replid:b2cfddd505444b7d7f9dcd694a7c808e10ee7b18
master_replid2:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
master_repl_offset:0
second_repl_offset:-1
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0

## CPU

used_cpu_sys:3.585386
used_cpu_user:4.473407
used_cpu_sys_children:0.000000
used_cpu_user_children:0.005857

## Modules

## Cluster

cluster_enabled:0

## Keyspace

db0:keys=5,expires=0,avg_ttl=0

--
The excersise is working without Debug mode!. ¿ i Miss some thing ?  ¿ waht be wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koACC.png)

- something in My Wls Workspace is Missing
- RedIS driver or version is not compatible with NODE 12.22.09
- RedIS driver or version is not compatible with VCOde
  Version: 1.79.2 (user setup)
  Commit: 695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06
  Date: 2023-06-14T08:57:04.379Z
  Electron: 22.5.7
  Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
  Node.js: 16.17.1
  V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
  OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621

Any Idea?
Thanks